# Control label position in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got this working code for plotting a histogram of my boostrap samples. I have added labels for the mean and 95% CIs, but they are placed at the bottom of the plot and are hard to read.  I want them at the top of the plot.  How do I accomplish this?

```
 # Plot the histogram and q-q plot using ggplot2
  hist_plot <- ggplot(data.frame(t = bo.mean$t), aes(x = t)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2, fill = "skyblue", color = "black", alpha = 0.7) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = c(ci_mean_values[1], bo.mean$t0, ci_mean_values[2]),
               linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
    geom_text(data = data.frame(x = c(ci_mean_values[1], bo.mean$t0, ci_mean_values[2]),
                                y = 0,
                                label = c("Lower CI", "Mean", "Upper CI"),
                                value = c(format(round(ci_mean_values[1], 2), nsmall = 2),
                                          format(round(bo.mean$t0, 2), nsmall = 2),
                                          format(round(ci_mean_values[2], 2), nsmall = 2))),
              aes(x = x, y = y, label = paste(label, ": ", value)),
              vjust = -.05, color = "red") +
    labs(title = paste("Device", i, "Histogram")) +
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1))
```

Comment: Use `y = Inf` where you have `y = y`?

Comment: Hmmm.  That took the labels completely off the plot (i'm guessing they went off frame)...

Comment: If you make the question reproducible you're more likely to get working answers that people can test. :-) You might need to adjust `vjust` to 1 or more to keep it in plot area.

Comment: `y= Inf` and `vjust=1` did it!  @jon_spring, if you post as answer I will accept...